# What is the difference between a coherent and an incoherent imaging system?

Tags: imaging

Could this please be explained in terms of an abstract system and then an imaging system?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Please enrich your question giving some context and explain what you know and what you don't more specifically, what kind of imaging systems do you refer to? As it stands you will get downvoted.

Comment: Do you mean a model for imaging systems that takes into account the coherence of the wavefield and multimoded behaviour? (as opposed to a coherent imaging system).